# how to animate a text in javafx using css?

Tags: java, css, javafx

i'm styling my javafx scene with css, and now i want to animate a text in a button on mouse hover. when i was reading similar questions here they say that it's not possible to do animation in css, and suggested to do animation in logic layer(clear, right?). anyway while i was searching IDE's suggestions, codes like:

animation-timing-function: ease-in;
where allowed, so it is possible.

my question is how to animate a text for example, using css. a sample code could be enough.
I also read JavaFX CSS Reference Guide, but i got nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX 2.2 and JavaFX 8 have no support for animating text using css.

Your IDE is being misleading in suggesting the `animation-timing-function` CSS attribute for use in a CSS file to be used only by JavaFX.  Most HTML type CSS attributes are unsupported by JavaFX.  JavaFX instead has its own CSS attribute definitions, usually prefixed by `-fx-`.  The set of supported CSS attributes for JavaFX is defined in the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Note that you can load HTML into a JavaFX application via [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) and that HTML can make use of [HTML CSS to perform animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) on the HTML document displayed in the WebView (not the JavaFX SceneGraph), but that is probably not what you wish to do.

Comment: will javafx maybe support them later?

Comment: Maybe cena, you can check the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) to see if a feature request has already been created.  I know the feature has been discussed by the JavaFX developers before and at the time there was interest in implementing it.  If there is no existing feature request, you can create one.